# Google AppEngine - Java - Slim3 - Show object (retrieved from a key) properties in a new view

Tags: java, model-view-controller, google-app-engine, parameter-passing

i'm a newbie Google AppEngine coder, so forgive my ignorance xD

I'm using the Slim3 MVC framework, so i'm coding in Java.

I've a list of objects showned in a view and i want to edit one single object by clicking on an apposite link. I provide an Edit controller with related view, i pass the key to the controller in this way:

Index.jsp [extract] (the view that lists all the objects):

```
<c:forEach var="tweet" items="${tweetList}">
    ...
    <a href="edit?key=${f:h(tweet.key)}">edit</a>
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

Edit controller:

```
    public class EditController extends Controller {

    @Override
    public Navigation run() throws Exception {
        Key tweetKey = asKey("key");
        return forward("edit.jsp");
    }
}
```

In the controller i can retrive the key from the url with

```
Key tweetKey = asKey("key");
```

But after what can i do for pass this key to view (edit view) and show exactly the object i want (assigned at the key retrieved)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered myself:

MyController.java [extract]

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    private MyService service = new MyService();

    @Override
    public Navigation run() throws Exception {
        Key myKey = asKey("key");
        MyObject myObject = service.getObject(myKey);
        requestScope("myObject", myObject);
        return forward("edit.jsp");
    }
}
```

Edit.jsp [extract]

```
...
<p>myObject properties:</p>
prop1: ${f:h(myObject.prop1)}<br />
prop2: ${f:h(myObject.prop2)}<br />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

tnx MASSIMILIANO.
for someone needs more detail:

editservice.java

```
...
private MyObjectMeta n = new MyObjectMeta();  

public news getObject(Key myKey) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Datastore.get(n, myKey);

}
...
```